# What are the use cases for using ImagePublishingRole in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Based on the documentation, its used for publishing assets.

> The file publishing role and the image publishing role are assumed by the AWS CDK Toolkit and by AWS CodeBuild projects to publish assets into an environment

I can imagine the use case for the file publishing role publishing files to central s3. Things like lambda code, cf templates, etc.

But for ImagePublishingRole, what are the use cases wherein you'll publish towards a central shared ECR repository?

Answer (score 0):

S3 can be used to store arbitrary blobs of data; including the examples you gave of lambda code and CF templates.

ECR is used to specifically store docker images.

So you would publish to this if you were deploying these images as part of your teams workflow. AWS services like Fargate, ECS and EKS will pull images from ECR and use the image to start services.

But, you can also push images to ECR and use that as your lambda runtime. So, ECR can end up hosting your lambda code.

Within the context of CDK, the CDK toolkit will need to push images to ECR when it’s deploying for these use cases.

Comment: So let's say it's used in ECS or Lambda, since this is a single ECR, does this mean different application instances (Fargate, Lambda, etc) would be sharing the same ECR?
Is that the intention?

Comment: That is what I believe is the intension. If you want to be more restrictive with your CDK bootstrap, see here https://betterdev.blog/cdk-bootstrap-least-deployment-privilege/

Comment: And you can see the exact permissions for that role here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-cdk/master/packages/aws-cdk/lib/api/bootstrap/bootstrap-template.yaml